# jHipster: Only exposing certain entities as REST endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I would like to set some configuration in the jdl (DSL) file for jHipster so that it does not expose REST endpoints for all entities. In my usecase, of the 10 or so entities, I would like to only expose endpoints for 3 of them - others are all nested inside one of the 3. Is this even possible? I couldn't find any documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible with the JDL, you must do it yourself.

Comment: oh no! I will add a feature request - maybe its useful enough for others that it can get implemented. If not, I will try to roll up my sleeves and try my hand at it. Thanks for the quick answer.